laerdal.dfu with maui while updating firmware it shows exception [DfuBaseService] An exception occurred while calculating file size
i have issue while updating the dfu.. i developing app with maui and i downloaded laerdal.dfu package from nuget for device firmware upgrade and i have downloaded new firmware zip file after building a nordic project and placed in my mobile phone so then i opened my connect with device and select the zip file but it throws an exception that [DfuBaseService] An exception occurred while calculating file size
[DfuBaseService] java.io.IOException: The ZIP file must contain an Application, a Soft Device and/or a Bootloader.
i am sharing the whole log as well in the form of picture below
enter image description here
so it should update the firmware but it shows the exception which i already mentioned above and share the log i hope to find any work around

Please read [ask] before posting.
